Double sum error message for NSum
I am attempting to evaluate
NSum[1/((2 i + 1)^4 + (2 j + 1)^4), {i, -1000, 1000}, {j, -1000, 1000}]

but it gives a negative value as the result; alongside an error message

NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit::seqlim: The general form of the sequence could not be determined, and the result may be incorrect.

What is the alternate/correct way for doing a similar calculation?

Slower and taking lots more memory, but no error message and no negative result N[Sum[1/((2i+1)^4+(2j+1)^4),{i,-600,600},{j,-600,600}],64] Depending on your plan you might be able to bump those 600 up to 1000 and take 3x longer to get get very very very close to the same result

Are you trying to sum to $\pm\infty$ or specifically to $\pm1000$?

@Roman  Originally it was to go to infinity. For various calculation of some reciprocals on lattice points of the plane.   However closed forms were not available and numerical calculations also bogged down.

Slow:
NSum[1/((2  i + 1)^4 + (2  j + 1)^4), {i, -1000, 1000}, {j, -1000, 
   1000}, NSumTerms -> 10000] // RepeatedTiming

(* {4.82287, 2.1729} *)

Somewhat fast:
Total[Table[
   1/((2  i + 1)^4 + (2  j + 1)^4) // N, {i, -1000, 1000}, {j, -1000, 
    1000}], All] // RepeatedTiming

(* {0.203502, 2.1729} *)

Very fast:
Total[
  Divide[
   1., 
   Outer[
    Plus,
    (2  N@Range[-1000, 1000] + 1)^4,
    (2  N@Range[-1000, 1000] + 1)^4]],
  All] // RepeatedTiming

(* {0.00499005, 2.1729} *)


Marginally faster, but not worth an edit: With[{x = Range[-1999., 2001., 2]^4}, Total[Divide[1., Outer[Plus, x, x]], All]]

What does NSum try to do in its simplest form that causes its error message and a negative answer?

@Maesumi Some sort of extrapolation or estimation (Wynn epsilon or Euler-Maclaurin usually). I'm not exactly sure how they work on nested sums. Unlike sum() on some other computer systems, both Sum and NSum try to find the sum without adding up the terms, unless the number of terms is small. Adding up terms is usually better done with Total. The above faster than the procedural sum = 0.; Do[sum += 1/((2 i + 1)^4 + (2 j + 1)^4), {i, -1000, 1000}, {j, -1000, 1000}]; sum, which is about as slow as NSum above.
